# EmailComposeTask / SmsComposeTask loses my app state

Tags: windows-phone-7, state

I'm developing my first Windows Phone 7 app. I don't yet have access to an actual device, so I am relying on the emulator that ships with the SDK.

In my app, I use the `EmailComposeTask` and `SmsComposeTask` where required. When debugging my app in the emulator, I click a button which runs one of these tasks, and it works. But when I then push the back button to get out of the task and back to my app, the app state is lost - it's as if I am launching it fresh all over again.

But, where it gets weird, is that on occasion this doesn't happen. I have gone back from one of the Tasks more than once to find my app state exactly how I left it.

And so, my questions:

1. Is this just a bug with the emulator?
2. If not, why is not consistent, and how should I be "saving" my app state prior to call the Email or SMS task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your page is being tombstoned which is why it seems like your application has restarted. This basically means that your app is still stored on the stack, ready to be called, but pages state and other data information is lost. To fix this, you need to handle the serialization of any data you want to keep.

For transient data, like page state things (e.g. textboxes, checkbox etc..), you can use [PhoneApplicationPage.State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.state%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). I believe the limit is `2mb`. If you need to store more, you should store it in Isolated Storage (unlikely, unless you need to save an image). You can read about the process [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817009%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). To understand the process of `Tombstoning`, you should read this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817008%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). To save time, you can use [Tombstone Helper](http://tombstonehelper.codeplex.com/) which handles all the lower level storage details for you, but it's a good idea to understand the process of Tombstoning anyway so you know what's going on.

The reason your app doesn't always get tombstoned is because `EmailComposeTask` doesn't cause a tombstone straight away. From this [MSDN blog post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg266434):

> Below is the list of native
>   experiences that, when invoked, do not
>   trigger an automatic tombstone in the
>   calling application:
>
> ```
> PhotoChooserTask
> CameraCaptureTask
> MediaPlayerLauncher
> EmailAddressChooserTask
> PhoneNumberChooserTask
> ```
>
> There are three scenarios in which an
>   application in the background will
>   immediately be tombstoned:
>
> ```
> User forward navigates away from an application [for example, user
> ```
>
> presses the Start key]
>       Application invokes launchers or choosers not listed above
>       System requires more resources to carry out a foreground activity

As you can see, that's not to say `EmailComposeTask` will never cause a tombstone, so you should still handle it, but it explains why your page state is sometimes kept automatically.